# How to count based on 2 columns, one that includes the [LEFT] function - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Find the value in `A2` which equals Level 1 in the sheet name Level 1 and count the number of entries where `'Level 1!'D2:D6` is Level 1 and the value in the next column `LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6"))=7`. The column `E2:E6` contains values such as `7 - 14. 7 - 10` etc. So, two conditions must be met, that two columns, `'Level 1'D2:D6` contains the value in `A2` which is `(Level 1)` and `'Level 1'E2:E6 LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6"))` is equal 7.

Here's a link to my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sqeJJdQRaz8oeE9wcsQDIkUywPyWR_KTgCzfvQiO2rY/edit?usp=sharing

I have tried this formula unsuccessfully:

`=COUNTA( IFERROR( FILTER( INDIRECT(A2&"!D2:D6") , INDIRECT(A2&"!D2:D6")=A2 , INDIRECT(A2&"!E2:E6"),LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6"))=7 )))`

The first part of my formula work, it returns the count where A2 (Level 1) appears in column `D2:D6`. The second part where we get the value `LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6"))=7` doesn't which means I'm not able to get the correct count that considers both conditions.

Please help me fix this.

Comment: If values are like `7 - 14`, why do you check equal to 7?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(N(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT('Level 1'!E2:E, "\d+")="7"))))
```

[image: 0]

---

#### UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(IF(('Level 1'!D$2:D=A2)*
 (7 >= REGEXEXTRACT('Level 1'!E$2:E, "\d+")    *1) * 
 (7 <= REGEXEXTRACT('Level 1'!E$2:E, "- (\d+)")*1), 1, ))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks but the intended result should be 2 because 7 at the end of the formula appears twice. Level 1 appears three times in the target column in Sheet "Level 1" but the next column contains the target number 7, twice. So the output should be 2.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the second criterion. If the value is supposed to be exactly equal to 7, none of them matches it. You can try this:

```
=COUNTIFS('Level 1'!D:D,"=" & A2, 'Level 1'!E:E, "=7")
```

If you want to match it with a pattern you can also try this `7 -*` as a pattern as well:

```
=COUNTIFS('Level 1'!D:D,"=" & A2, 'Level 1'!E:E, "7 -*")
```

You can use `INDIRECT` to construct the reference to the intended sheet, or if want to take the value of the lower bound from another cell (let's say `A3`) you can construct the pattern with `A3 & " -*"`:

```
=COUNTIFS('Level 1'!D:D,"=" & A2, INDIRECT(A2&"!E:E"), A3 & " -*" )
```

Comment: 7 - 14 is a range for the age bracket. So I wanted to check when the left part is equal to 7. It looks like the pattern formula you provided above is working. Thanks

Comment: Is there an alternative to the pattern such as a formula like this LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6"))=7  that checks whether the first part of the text 7 - 14 is equal to 7. The first part of the text 7 - 14 is dynamic so a formula will really help. In the formula LEFT(INDIRECT(A2&"!$E$2:$E$6")) is 7, it checks whether the first part from the left is 7 but I however much I try, I am unable to add to the last part of the formula you gave to avoid using pattern because of the dynamic values.

Comment: You can make the pattern dynamic: `A3  & " -*"`.